# URLS in GET MVC 4 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement where

> GET /Api/Customers/1/URL.

So I modified

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "MyApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/Customers/{action}/{CustID}/{URL}",
                 defaults: new { Controller = "Customers", custID = @"\d+", URL = @"[\/\/\w.:?\/\/=&]" }
```

I also changed web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

When I run my application and type in localhost/Api/Customers/GetDetails/1/http://www.test.com,

--GetDetails

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public void GetDetails(int CustID, string URL_FilePath)
{
    Customer newcust = new Customer();
    newcust.CustID = CustID;

    newcust.URL_FilePath = URL_FilePath;
    Post(newcust);
}


[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public void Post([FromBody]Customer value)
{
        //call database procedure and pass Customer object and commit
        //If exception show error
}
```

I get Server Error in '/' Application.
Where is error coming from? How can allow urls?

Comment: Escaping them. If you don't it's hard to distinguish between separators from url or from parameter...

Comment: Technically this is web api and not mvc right?

Comment: can you take it as a query string parameter instead of directly in the URI?

Comment: @Madullah, you mean, Have 2 text boxes.make user enter ID,URL and submit button. I tried that & it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several ways how to resolve the issue:

First. Add setting to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Use the * in your route configuration for the URL parameter:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MyApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Customers/{action}/{CustID}/{*URL_FilePath}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "Customers", custID = @"\d+" , URL = @"[\/\/\w.:?\/\/=&]" });
```

The * causes all remaining address to be passed to this parameter. The issue I found when testing on my machine is that if you pass the full url like

```
http://localhost/Api/Customers/getDetails/1/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com
```

repeating slashes are removed and the posted value is http:/www.test.com. You could quite easily update the url to add extra slash here in your controller method. I did not investigate if it has something to do with browser or web server settings.

The second option is not to add URL_FilePath to the route, and pass it as query string parameter:

```
routeTemplate: "api/Customers/{action}/{CustID}"
```

And use request like this:

```
http://yourservername/Api/Customers/getDetails/1?URL_FilePath=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com.
```

In this case parameter value is correct (with all slashes in place). In this case you don't need a setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to be set to true.

Comment: Try removing URL restrictions from defaults in your route configuration. It is very likely that you need different regular expression when you have encoded url value

Comment: tried config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "MyApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/Customers/{action}/{CustID}/{URL}",
                 defaults: new { Controller = "Customers"}); It doesn't work

Comment: Action name seems to be also missing. Is it index? In that case try address localhost/Api/Customers/Index/1/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com

Comment: oops!! action name is getDetails (GET in Customers controller)

Comment: What is the method signature of getDetails method? Can you show the code please?

Comment: I did a deeper investigation and updated the answer above with what I've found

Comment: thanks for explaining to me about runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests. For now, my manager agreed with your 2nd suggestion- sending as parameters.I have changed my program & it works :-)